# Encrypt in CryptoJS and decrypt in NodeJS Crypto module

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptojs, node-crypto

I have searched here and googled, but couldn't really find what I am looking for. Looks like this should be pretty easy but few similar threads went unanswered as SO. I am hoping if I get the answer. So I have this fiddle [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vikasbhandari2/4ovzwbnk/15/) which encrypts and decrypts in CryptoJS, no problem so far. Code is here:

```
var options = { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7, keySize: 256 };  

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('encrypt me', 'A37u172sSFS9O9JNHs82u38djdncnvyz', options);


var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "A37u172sSFS9O9JNHs82u38djdncnvyz", options);  
var plaintext = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

But when I take the encrypted string, and I try to decrypt, I am unable to. See this node fiddle: [Node Fiddle](https://runkit.com/vikas-eb/5b8e65c02b73f60012d271c3), and code is:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const mykey = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', 'A37u172sSFS9O9JNHs82u38djdncnvyz');

//A37u172sSFS9O9JNHs82u38djdncnvyz9
const mystr = mykey.update('U2FsdGVkX18mFQOkolgDJ0cjOfYqiqKCUGdNoA2nESI=', 'base64', 'utf8');
```

Ideally, the mystr string should return to me the text 'encrypt me', but it shows some gibberish characters. I know it should be easy to find, but I am unable to understand what I am doing wrong. I am totally noob when it comes to encryption. Any help here?

Comment: what version of node are you using?

Comment: I'm using v8.12.0

Comment: were you able to fix this?

Comment: hell no. But what I did is that I built an es5 module using crypto-js and use it at both the ends. I will love if anyone has the solution as I am very bad with the encryption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old post but I just did the opposite of this it should be relevant, posting this as I didnt find any other similar article on here.

Encrypt Node JS Crypto.

```
const key = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(String(random)).digest();
const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
return cipher.update(JSON.stringify(data || {}), 'utf8', 'base64') + cipher.final('base64');
```

Decrypt in CryptoJS

```
const key = CryptoJS.SHA256(randomString) // same string as encrypt
const plaintextArray = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
    {
      ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(data),
      salt: ''
    },
    key,
    { iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv), mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC }
  )
  return CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(plaintextArray)
```